# Change Column Type for multiple tables with same column name

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database that keeps track of the user that made an update or insert and when they did it for each table in the database.   We've got a need to change the type from varchar(20) to varchar(50).  Is there a way to write a script that will delve into all of the tables that have that column name and change it from varchar(20) to varchar(50).

This is on a MS SQL 2012 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script will generate statements to alter the columns.

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' NVARCHAR(50)'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%columniwantchanged%'
```